# Error when trying to send data from APIClient to a function using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, betfair, apiclient

Betfairlightweight API: https://github.com/betcode-org/betfair

To work with this module, it is necessary to pass the APIClient data and login:

```py
trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username, pw, app_key=app_key, cert_files=('blablabla.crt','blablabla.key'))
trading.login()
```

To speed up the data collection process, I'm use multiprocessing:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username, pw, app_key=app_key, cert_files=('blablabla.crt','blablabla.key'))
trading.login()

def main():
    matches_bf = # DataFrame...
    try:
        max_process = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 or 1
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
        list_pool = pool.map(data_event, matches_bf.iterrows())
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    trading.logout()

def data_event(event_bf):
    _, event_bf = event_bf
    event_id = event_bf['event_id']
    filter_catalog_markets = betfairlightweight.filters.market_filter(
        event_ids=[event_id],
        market_type_codes = [
            'MATCH_ODDS'
            ]
        )

    catalog_markets = trading.betting.list_market_catalogue(
        filter=filter_catalog_markets,
        max_results='100',
        sort='FIRST_TO_START',
        market_projection=['RUNNER_METADATA']
    )

     ... # some more code
     ... # some more code
     ... # some more code
```

That way *12 logins* are made. For accessing an API, this is not the ideal way.

***Why 12 logins?***

When I activate the code it makes 1 login and when the multiprocessing pool is created, it generates 11 more logins, one for each process. If I put `print(trading)` exactly below `trading.login()`, one print statement appears in the terminal when the code starts to run, then another 11 happen simultaneously when the pool is created.

So I need to find a way to be able to do this same service using only **ONE** *login*.

I tried to throw the *login* inside `main()` and add as an argument to call the function:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat

def main():
    trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username, pw, app_key=app_key, cert_files=('blablabla.crt','blablabla.key'))
    trading.login()

    matches_bf = # DataFrame...
    try:
        max_process = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 or 1
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
        list_pool = pool.map(data_event, zip(repeat(trading),matches_bf.iterrows()))
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    trading.logout()

def data_event(trading,event_bf):
    trading = trading
    _, event_bf = event_bf
    event_id = event_bf['event_id']
    filter_catalog_markets = betfairlightweight.filters.market_filter(
        event_ids=[event_id],
        market_type_codes = [
            'MATCH_ODDS'
            ]
        )

    catalog_markets = trading.betting.list_market_catalogue(
        filter=filter_catalog_markets,
        max_results='100',
        sort='FIRST_TO_START',
        market_projection=['RUNNER_METADATA']
    )

     ... # some more code
     ... # some more code
     ... # some more code
```

But the error encountered is:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object
```

I tried to put `trading` inside the function `data_event`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username, pw, app_key=app_key, cert_files=('blablabla.crt','blablabla.key'))
    trading.login()

    matches_bf = # DataFrame...
    try:
        max_process = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 or 1
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
        list_pool = pool.map(data_event, matches_bf.iterrows())
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    trading.logout()

def data_event(event_bf):
    trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username, pw, app_key=app_key, cert_files=('blablabla.crt','blablabla.key'))
    _, event_bf = event_bf
    event_id = event_bf['event_id']
    filter_catalog_markets = betfairlightweight.filters.market_filter(
        event_ids=[event_id],
        market_type_codes = [
            'MATCH_ODDS'
            ]
        )

    catalog_markets = trading.betting.list_market_catalogue(
        filter=filter_catalog_markets,
        max_results='100',
        sort='FIRST_TO_START',
        market_projection=['RUNNER_METADATA']
    )

     ... # some more code
     ... # some more code
     ... # some more code
```

But the error encountered is:

```
errorCode': 'INVALID_SESSION_INFORMATION'
```

The reason is logical: multiprocessing did not login.

How should I proceed so that I use only one login and can do everything I need without being forced to work one by one (line by line without multiprocessing takes too long, not feasible)?

**Additional info:**

- [*betfairlightweight* login](https://github.com/betcode-org/betfair/blob/master/betfairlightweight/endpoints/login.py) if it helps in understanding the case:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `session` for `betfairlightweight.APIClient` instance to be pickleable.

```py
trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(
    username,
    pw,
    app_key=app_key,
    cert_files=('blablabla.crt','blablabla.key'),
    session=requests.Session(),  # Add this
)
```

## Explanation

> TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object

`APIClient` (`BaseClient`) defaults `self.session` to the `requests` module.

```py
class APIClient(BaseClient):
    ...
```

```py
class BaseClient:
    ...

    def __init__(
        self,
        username: str,
        password: str = None,
        app_key: str = None,
        certs: str = None,
        locale: str = None,
        cert_files: Union[Tuple[str], str, None] = None,
        lightweight: bool = False,
        session: requests.Session = None,
    ):
        ...

        self.session = session if session else requests
        ...
```

Comment: Hi @aaron works perfectly with ```list_pool = pool.map(data_event, zip(repeat(trading), events_bf.iterrows()))``` and ```def data_event(event_bf):``` → ```trading = event_bf[0]``` → ```_, event_bf = event_bf[1]```. Just to add, working with ```zip``` and opening with index ```[0]``` and ```[1]``` inside the function is the best thing to do or is there a more professional way to pass this argument?

Comment: Maybe `pool.starmap` with `def data_event(trading, event_bf)`.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread is executing the `login` operation, so putting the login logic in a function that is invoked via `if __name__ == ...` should fix the issue by shielding it from the threads.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username, pw, app_key=app_key, cert_files=('blablabla.crt','blablabla.key'))
    trading.login()
    trading.keep_alive()

    matches_bf = # DataFrame...
    try:
        max_process = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 or 1
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
        m = multiprocessing.Manager()
        queue = m.Queue()
        queue.put(trading)
        list_pool = pool.starmap(data_event, [(queue, row) for row in matches_bf.iterrows()])
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    trading.logout()

def data_event(queue, event_bf):
    trading = queue.get()
    _, event_bf = event_bf
     ... # some more code
    queue.put(trading)

if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

#### Edit

The main issue here is, the `trading` object (basically the API client returned by the trading library) can not be serialized, because of which `multiprocessing` fails to pickle it and send it to processes. As I see it, there's no "direct" solution to your question; however, you can try either of these workarounds:

1. Instead of multiprocessing, try using [pathos.multiprocessing](https://pathos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pathos.html), which used `dill` instead of `pickle`.
2. Instead of using `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, you could use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`. Since it shares memory with the main thread, each sub-process wouldn't need to create a new trading object. This *might* come at a performance hit in comparison to `Pool` though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245123/discussion-between-abhinav-mathur-and-digital-farmer).