# How to call a function that is inside another function using pool multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I need to run the same function 10 times that for reasons of data linked to a login, it needs to be inside another function:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    def inside(a):
        print(a)
    Pool.map(inside, 'Ok' * 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    def inside(a):
        print(a)
    Pool.map(main.inside, 'Ok' * 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In both attempts the result is this:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'map'
```

How can I do this by keeping the function inside the other function?
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: the error is because .map is not an attribute/method of Pool - Pool is a function (technically a method)

Comment: [Pool usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5442910/15740324)

Comment: You have to invoke `.map()` on an *instance* of `Pool`, rather than the class itself.  But I don't think this will work even after you fix that problem - the function being run has to have a globally-defined name, so that a reference to it can be transferred to a different process, and that's simply not true for a nested function.

Comment: Hi friends, thanks for the comments. Can help me think of an option that would work for my need for a function within another function? I couldn't find an option. Because of the data created for ```API Client```, I can't put this function outside the other function. I even have a question that explains why I can't use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890447/error-when-trying-to-send-data-from-apiclient-to-a-function-using-multiprocessin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'map'
```

We need to instantiate `Pool` from `multiprocessing` and call `map` method of that pool object.

You have to move `inside` method to some class because Pool uses pickel to **serialize** and **deserialize** methods and if its inside some method then it cannot be **imported** by `pickel`.

> Pool needs to pickle (serialize) everything it sends to its
> worker-processes (IPC). Pickling actually only saves the name of a
> function and unpickling requires re-importing the function by name.
> For that to work, the function needs to be defined at the top-level,
> nested functions won't be importable by the child and already trying
> to pickle them raises an exception (more).

Please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265120/python-multiprocessing-pool-attributeerror) of SO.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Wrap:
    def inside(self, a):
        print(a)

def main():
    pool = Pool() 
    pool.map(Wrap().inside, 'Ok' * 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you don't want to wrap `inside` method inside of a `class` move the `inside` method to global scope so it can be **pickled**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def inside(a):
    print(a)

def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(inside, 'Ok'*10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```